# Qt Speed Gauge to Accept and display an input number

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

I am new to Qt. I am a hardware guy. I wanted to use Qt for displaying the benchmark results of a code (execution time) for a demo. I thought it would be more presentable if I displayed it in a visually appealing manner.

I came across a example implementation of a Speed gauge in Qt at this link:
https://github.com/Berrima/Qt-custom-gauge-widget/tree/master/examples/SpeedGauge

I want to display a number (say 900) on the speed gauge and this can be done by setting a value of the needle. But I want the needle to gradually increase and stop at 900.

Can someone please give me some idea how to proceed on this as I am very new to this and I have limited time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html .